# Existence of smallest closed sub-$T$-algebra

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In Johnstone's Sketch of Elephant. Page 1034, section D5.1, Lemma 5.1.1 says:

Any $T$-algebra contains a unique smallest closed subobject, which is recursive.

In the proof of "Any $T$-algebra contains a unique smallest closed subobject". He says:

> An arbitrary intersection of sub-$T$-algebra is a sub-$T$-algebra, so we may obtain the smallest one by forming the intersection of all of them.

My question is that this proof mentions "arbitrary intersection", which may not exist in a category that is not complete (even in a topos under Lawvere's ETCS definition, we can only take finite limit). Does this proof assume that we are working in a complete category? If it does not, how does it work if we do not assume arbitrary limit exists?

Comment: Isn’t Part D about classifying toposes, hence Grothendieck toposes, which are complete?

Comment: @ZhenLin D3 is about classifying toposes, but according to the table of contents I do not think the whole part D is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lemma in question concerns the algebraic theory $\mathbb{T}$ freely generated by a constant and a unary operation.
This is important because it means the structure of a $\mathbb{T}$-algebra can be expressed in the internal logic of elementary toposes.
In particular, the property of a subobject of the underlying object of a $\mathbb{T}$-algebra being a sub-$\mathbb{T}$-algebra can be expressed in the internal logic.
Therefore we may form (as a subobject of the powerobject) the object of all sub-$\mathbb{T}$-algebras.
Being indexed by a subobject of the powerobject, we can therefore take the intersection of all sub-$\mathbb{T}$-algebras of the given $\mathbb{T}$-algebra.
All this happens in the internal logic, so there is no need to invoke any external completeness.

Moral: if something looks like it needs infinite limits or colimits but you need it to work in an elementary topos, try using internal logic instead.